# A blockchain to read events from another blockchain

Tags: pallet, rpc, substrate-node, custom-rpc

I'm working on an idea where I would want my substrate-based blockchain (let's name it Blockchain A) to read events from another substrate-based blockchain (let's call it Blockchain B) and perform some actions on the basis of those events. For example, let's suppose I would want to read the TX events from Blockchain B so that when there's a TX of more than 100 tokens, I would want my Blockchain A to trigger an action in response to that event.

Is it possible to build something like this in Substrate? I've seen that there's this [substrate_rpc_client](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/substrate_rpc_client/index.html) pallet that has some helpful methods to do this, but I'm not sure where I would configure it in the outer node of my blockchain.

Any help in this regard is quite appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**With the help of XCM you can do this.**

Implementing `cross-chain` communication, such as through the `XCM protocol`, can be challenging due to the lack of comprehensive documentation. However, you can draw inspiration from successful implementations of the `cumulus git hub` [you can get a idea from pink-pong pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus) By leveraging your ingenuity, you can devise a strategy to integrate XCM-like functionality into your blockchain. This will involve understanding the underlying principles of cross-chain messaging, designing a compatible architecture, and ensuring robust security measures.

Comment: I doubt that XCM could help me in this regard. I don't want Blockchain A to send any type of confirmation to Blockchain B, whether it has performed any action or not. I just want Blockchain A to read events from Blockchain B and invoke its own implementation independent of Blockchain B.

Comment: You can draw inspiration from the Ping Pong pallet, which is available on a GitHub repository I provided your before. This pallet offers valuable insights into implementing cross-chain communication. By studying its codebase and design, you can gain a clearer understanding of how to integrate similar functionality into your own blockchain project.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible to design an application with an event subscriber with the help of [polkadot-js](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/events/) and then use it also to submit events to your blockchain B. However the process can be quite involved depending on what you want to do. I suggest going through the documentation on submitting extrinsics and reading events.